# Desktop notification for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is there any way to get desktop notification for Stack Overflow? I would like to know that someone has answered, commented, or voted on my question or answer without visiting the Stack Overflow webpage, and then I can visit Stack Overflow.

I spend a lot of time in refreshing the Stack Overflow page to see notifications.

Comment: I don't know if there is one... but I'd find this useful too. I guess we're in the right place for someone to develop one if there isn't one already lol.

Comment: Ya we should if we don't have any such thing :)

Comment: @Numenor: Don't know exactly as I am new to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-1-r) on Stack Apps. I haven't used it, but it looks like it should work quite well for what you need.

Comment: @James:After looking at comments ,(Seems) This is what I was looking for. Thanks man :)

Comment: @James: I tried it but no luck. It is successfully installed but showing options No accounts(disabled),Network error,Network error, Tools (Disabled),Refresh,Preference,About,Quit.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackapps.com/questions/3982/live-desktop-alert-for-stackoverflow