# List of duplicate questions when question voted down as dupe

Tags: feature-request

I would like to see a separate list of "Links to Duplicate Questions" when a question gets closed as a dupe. The current "Links" list appears to be just a general listing and does not always include a duplicate question (unlikely but: perhaps because I have a more sharpened skill when reading questions and answers?).
The idea would be that the people voting the question down as a dupe can provide specific links so the questioner can get their answer.

***Is this something you are willing to implement?***

(Please be nice: I'm still new to SE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a question is closed as a duplicate, the duplicate questions are shown at the top of the closed question, in a "Possible Duplicate" box.

See [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95752/desktop-notification-for-stack-overflow), for example.

Comment: As well as in the auto-comment - and to be fair, it's not "voted down". Of course, those links disappear after the question is closed, but anyone is free to point OP to helpful resources regardless of close vote.

Comment: For clarification, is the "Possible Duplicate" box automated, or do users link that duplicate? Also, is the duplicate link mandatory? The latter two questions will resolve my request, i.e. that the feature is already implemented.

Comment: @Telis: It's automated. And yes, you have to specify a question when you vote to close as a duplicate.